# jQuery's '.focus()' not behaving like I'd expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I've programmed some simple PHP "merge tags" for use in a form. I'd love for them to be 'clickable' to input into a text box.

I've got some basic code, that "works". It puts the merge tags in, and refocuses the box - but it puts the cursor behind anything you've typed, but in front of all the merge tags?

If I type:

```
[Howdy ]
```

and click on `{firstname}`, I get:

```
[Howdy {firstname}]
```

which is great!

But the cursor is between "howdy" and `{firstname}` like so:

```
[Howdy |{firstname}]
```

I've got a [very simple fiddle set up](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/GCpvy/) to showcase what the issue is. I've been trying to use `.val()` and `.focus()` together

Comment: I believe this only affects Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `selectionStart` property to the sum of the current `selectionStart` and the length of the string you are adding.

```
$("#test").prop('selectionStart', function (_, ss) {
    return ss + mtag.length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GCpvy/1/

Comment: Funny, I can't see any difference from the OP's jsFiddle using Firefox.

Comment: @jtheman - apparently according to Jacob VanScoy it's a 'chrome' issue. I use Chrome 99% of the time.

Explosion Pills - thank you! It works wonderfully!! :D

Answer (score 2):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCpvy/2/)**

Just adjust the text area's `selectionStart` variable like this:

```
$('#test')[0].selectionStart = $('#test').val().length;
```